# ITextSharp rotate all text on a page about a point

Tags: .net, pdf, rotation, itext, affinetransform

I've just burnt an hour working out a solution to this, which I'm sure isn't the best one; I'd be happy to hear if there is a better solution.

I need to rotate all text on a page about a point.  I've tried transforming the point to the origin, performing a rotation and then transforming back, but it seems like the final transformation is happening relative to the rotation transform (which, thinking about it, makes sense).

Here's a reduced complexity version of my code:

```
imports itextsharp.text

public class Example

    public shared function RotateAboutPoint(byval sourceReader as pdf.pdfreader, byval rads as double, byval centreX as double, byval centreY as double) as pdf.pdfreader            

        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            Using doc As New Document
                Using writer As pdf.PdfWriter = pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)
                    doc.Open()
                    For i As Integer = 1 To sourceReader.NumberOfPages
                        Dim p As pdf.PdfTemplate = writer.GetImportedPage(sourceReader, i)

                        dim trans as new itextsharp.awt.geom.affinetransform
                        trans.translate(-centrex, -centrey)
                        trans.rotate(-rads)
                        trans.translate(centerx, centery)

                        doc.setpagesize(sourcereader.getpagesizewithrotation(I))
                        doc.newpage()

                        writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(p, trans)
                    Next i
                    doc.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
            sourceReader.Close()
            sourceReader.Dispose()
            return New pdf.PdfReader(ms.ToArray)
        End Using
    end function
end class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solutions I've come upon, basically perform the rotation without translation, then translates by the addition of two vectors, one which gets from the rotation origin to the required centre of rotation and one which gets from (the place that the required centre of rotation will have been rotated to) to the rotation origin

```
imports itextsharp.text

public class Example

    public shared function RotateAboutPoint(byval sourceReader as pdf.pdfreader, byval rads as double, byval centreX as double, byval centreY as double) as pdf.pdfreader            

        Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            Using doc As New Document
                Using writer As pdf.PdfWriter = pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)
                    doc.Open()
                    For i As Integer = 1 To sourceReader.NumberOfPages
                        Dim p As pdf.PdfTemplate = writer.GetImportedPage(sourceReader, i)

                        Dim transAdjust As New iTextSharp.awt.geom.AffineTransform
                        transAdjust.SetToIdentity()
                        transAdjust.Translate(centreX - ((centreX * System.Math.Cos(rads)) + (centreY * System.Math.Sin(rads))), centreY - ((centreX * -System.Math.Sin(rads)) + (centreY * System.Math.Cos(rads))))
                        Dim transRotate As New iTextSharp.awt.geom.AffineTransform
                        transRotate.SetToIdentity()
                        transRotate.Rotate(-rads)

                        Dim finalTrans As New iTextSharp.awt.geom.AffineTransform
                        finalTrans.SetToIdentity()
                        finalTrans.Concatenate(transAdjust)
                        finalTrans.Concatenate(transRotate)

                        doc.setpagesize(sourcereader.getpagesizewithrotation(I))
                        doc.newpage()

                        writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(p, finalTrans)
                    Next i
                    doc.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
            sourceReader.Close()
            sourceReader.Dispose()
            return New pdf.PdfReader(ms.ToArray)
        End Using
    end function
end class
```

It feels messy, but it works - I'd be very interested if there was a simpler way using combinations of transformations and rotations.

Comment: If the rotation angle can only be 0, 90, 180 or 270 (and no value in-between), then there's a much easier way to achieve your goal. If the angle can have *any* value (not just a multiple of 90), then you indeed need to do the math and using `AffineTransform` is the more *human-readable* way to do it (although it still looks complex).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for your comment.  I'm afraid I need to rotate by arbitrary amounts, so I can't use the page rotation thingie.  Are you aware of an easier method to achieve my goal using chained AffineTransforms without all the trigonometry?

Comment: You could calculate "multiply" the different transformations, resulting in 6 values `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` that are required when you use the other `AddTemplate()` method. The `e` and `f` value define the translation. In case of a rotation, `a` and `d` will be `0` whereas `b` will be `-sin(angle)` and `d` will be `cos(angle)`. Check section 4.2.5.1 of [The ABC of PDF with iText](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc) for the correct Math (I'm just writing this from the top of my head).